# Using Office UI Fabric (without react and angular?)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, reactjs, office365-apps, office-fabric

I'm working on a simple add-in for Word Online (created using the `Visual C# \ Office/Sharepoint \ Web Add-ins \ Word Add-in` template in Visual Studio), and need to show a simple input-form.

The add-in web-content is based on a `C# MVC web application` (replacing the default web-project, associated via the `Web Project` property on the add-in project).

For this I wish to use `Office Fabric UI` to ensure the style will seem familiar to my users.
It's also added automatically when associating the MVC project with the add-in project, though referencing an older version of the Fabric UI nuGet package, I have updated to the latest version 2.6.3.

I need to use regular inputs such as `textboxes`, `textareas` and `comboboxes`.

I see examples on how to do this on the [official site](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fabric), but all these components require `reactjs`.

I have zero experience with `reactjs` and `angularjs`, and is used to writing the html markup myself (using the @Html razor-helpers etc).
But I can't seem to find any examples on how to do this manually anywhere, for Fabric UI components.

So... What can I do to use these components in my `C# MVC application`?

Answer (score -3):

You can use these components to build `Single Page Application (SPA)` for Front End.

Backend will be `ASP.NET MVC` framework with `C#` language.

`React` and `Angular` Components are really useful to build the UI blocks and make that block reusable.

you can check the below link for more information.

https://reactjs.net/

Comment: He specifically asked if/how to do it WITHOUT React or Angular